# Live search of the picture_name

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

The names of picture from database do not appear when I'm typing its letters in the input of my form. I'm trying to implement the live search on my page. I got MySql database called 'pinterest' with table 'pictures' and 'picture_name' column with different names of picture. I want these names to appear when I'm typing letters of it in the input of my form. NOTHING WORKS :-(

I got MySql Database, php form and ajax request.

file : search.php:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/connect.php';
?>

<form id="frmSearch" method="post" action="search.php">
<label>Pickup location <br>
      <input type="text" name="txtSearchPictureName" id="txtSearchPictureName" placeholder="Search.." list="searchList" required>
      <datalist id="searchList"></datalist>
    </label>
</form>

<script src="search.js"></script>
```

file : search.js

```
$('#txtSearchPictureName').on('input', function(val){
    $.ajax({
      method : "GET",
      url : 'apis/api-search-picture.php?txtSearchPictureName='+val.target.value,
      cache: false,
      dataType:"JSON"
    }).
    done( function(jData){
        $('#searchList').empty()
        jData.forEach(x => {
            $('#searchList').append('<option value="' + x.picture_name + '"></option>')
        })
    }).
    fail( function(){

    })
  })
```

file: api-search-picture.php

````
<?php

 //connection do db
 require_once __DIR__.'/connect.php';

$sPictureName = $_GET['txtSearchPictureName'];


try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT picture_name FROM pictures WHERE picture_name LIKE :sPictureName ');
    $stmt->bindValue(':sPictureName', "%$sPictureName%"); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $aRows = $stmt->fetchAll();


    echo json_encode($aRows);


} catch(PDOEXception $ex){
    echo $ex;
}
```
````

Comment: Could you be more specific, please? Have you checked the network requests to the server and the response?

Comment: I tried to write in my URL the name of one image that I got stored in database but no response. ```apis/api-search-picture.php?txtSearchPictureName=paleta```

Comment: Then why have you shown us the Ajax and HTML? It distracts from the problem. Can you show us how you make the PDO connection? Do you enable the exception mode?

Comment: @DharmanAlright so typing in url http://localhost:8888/pinterest/apis/api-search-picture.php?txtSearchPictureName= doesnt me any results. In connect.php ? ```<?php
try{
  $sUserName = 'root';
  $sPassword = 'root';
  $sConnection = "mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pinterest; charset=utf8mb4";
  $aOptions = array(
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ
  );
  $db = new PDO( $sConnection, $sUserName, $sPassword, $aOptions );
}catch( PDOException $e){
  echo '{"status":0,"message":"cant connect"}';
  exit();